# How can I formally prove a set does not have any isolation points?

Tags: general-topology

I have the set $A = (0,1)$ and I want to prove that this set does not have any isolation points. I know that a point $a \in A$ is in isolation point of $A$ if it is not a limit point in $A$. Would it be sufficient enough to say that if I knew the limit points of $A$ were $0$ and $1$ respectively, that the isolation point is $a \in A$ such that $a \neq 0 \ \land 1$?

Answer (score 0):

$A$ has no isolated point if all element of $A$ are limit point. In you example, $0$ and $1$ are in fact limits points, but all point of $(0,1)$ are also limit point since the clasure of $(0,1)$ is $[0,1]$. Let me know if I didn't answer correctly to your question.